# How to join (connect) strings without newlines into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, string, file, codeigniter

Today I found some strange bug in my code.

I generate street, street number and save it into MySQL Address column.
It looks ok in application, but in MySQL theres a newline between street name and street number:

```
Konopnickiej
 4/20
```

In frontend there's everything ok. When I just edit this record (without editing - just send this same data to edited record) in frontend - MySQL save this as:

```
Konopnickiej 4/20
```

So how to fix that joins in generating script?

```
$ulice = file(base_url('/assets/admin/ulice.txt'));

$adres = trim($ulice[array_rand($ulice)] . ' ' . $this->_generateAddressNumber());
```

Comment: In the front end, is everything okay if you wrap the output in `<pre>` tags, or does the newline exist?

Comment: @Sundar: That is wrong, and really terrible advice.

Comment: this is the way we can escape the carriage return/new line characters

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've got this.

```
$ulica = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $ulice[array_rand($ulice)]);

$adres = trim($ulica. ' ' .$this->_generateAddressNumber());
```